# Prevent users from modifying data in Firebase but allow this data to be updated by the application

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I create an app with GatsbyJS (React) + Firebase.

Users have a score saved in Firebase Realtime Database with their data.

```
{
  users: {
    $uid: {
      score: 10,
      name: "Antho",
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

I do not want users to be able to change their score themselves, so I split my database like this:

```
{
  users: {
    $uid: {
      name: "uciska",
      ...
    }
  },
  scores: {
    $uid: {
      score: 10
    }
  }
}
```

But I do not know what rules to put in place.

I think I need some backend code. If so I would like to go through Amazon Lambda functions without having to set up a Node.js server.

Is it possible ? Where to start ?

Could Cloud Firestore do that more simply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want your user to be able to write the scores, you can simple use these [rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/):

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".write": "auth.uid == $uid"
      }
    }
    "scores": {
      ".write": false // this is not strictly needed, since the default is false
    }
  }
}
```

With this, each [user can write their own node](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/user-security) under `/users/$uid` and no user can write any score.

Next, you'll want to use the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/start) in a trusted environment to write the scores. A trusted environment is something you control access to, such as a server, your development machine, or [Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/). Code that runs in Cloud Functions, or otherwise uses the Admin SDK, has administrative privileges, which means it bypasses the security rules. So that code can read/write the entire database, including the scores.